# Recognizing an array of constructor

Tags: ruby

What can I do to recognize an array which is declared in a constructor, by method, in this class?

I received an error:

> undefined local variable or method 'myArray'

```
class Calc
    def initialize()
        myArray = []
    end

    def add4ToArray()
        myArray.push(4)
        puts myArray.size
    end
end

obj1 = Calc.new
obj1.add4ToArray()
```

Comment: A common convention is to use full-downcase snake_case for method names. Call print/puts etc during the method call, don't put these in the method definition. No need to add `()` to your method name if your method isn't defining any parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare it as an instance variable as opposed to a local variable. In the constructor, use `@myarray = []`.

Comment: Do you mean `@myarray = []`?

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the catch